# Domain routing to url in Apache httpd.conf

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I was wondering if there's a way to route a domain request (www.example.com) to (https://otherdomain.com/post) via httpd.conf?

I have a url redirect setup at godaddy but I'm getting redirect loop errors on some browsers (whole different problem). So I'm trying this route.

In theory I would point my domain (www.example.com) to XX.XXX.XX.XXX where apache would route that to a custom url (https://otherdomain.com/post).

I'm running Laravel 4 with forced SSL on (https://otherdomain.com)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX>
ServerName directtolinux.com
ServerAlias www.directtolinux.com
ServerAlias www.direct-to-linux.com
ServerAlias digitalpenguins.com
ServerAlias www.digitalpenguins.com
Redirect permanent / http://www.yolinux.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

or for multiple domains

```
#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.com
    Redirect / http://www.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    . . .
    . . .
</VirtualHost>
```

Sources

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-temporary-and-permanent-redirects-with-apache-and-nginx

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/ApacheRedirect.html